# adding rows to pandas df with values merging with all previous values

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe df:

```
name  id  value   id_2  value_2
a    1    10.5    2     20.3
a    1    10.5    3     30.1
a    2    20.3    1     10.5
a    2    20.3    3     30.1
a    3    30.1    1     10.5
a    3    30.1    2     20.3
```

note: `for id 1 value = 10.5, id 2 value = 20.3, id 3 value = 30.1`

You can clearly see that each id has been merged with every other id in dataframe.

I want to add a new row in dataframe with `id = 4` and `value = 40.7`

Such that the final dataframe looks like:

```
name  id  value   id_2  value_2
a    4    40.7    1     10.5
a    4    40.7    2     20.3
a    4    40.7    3     30.1
a    1    10.5    4     40.7
a    2    20.3    4     40.7
a    3    30.1    4     40.7
```

Comment: I think your last record, on your input df, is incorrect. Shouldn't it be [a,3,*30.1*,2,20.3]?

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for correcting me, i edited question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df_new_row = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a'],'id':[4],'value':[40.7]})

df_l = df[['id','value']].drop_duplicates().assign(key=1).merge(df_new_row.assign(key=1),on='key',suffixes=('','_2'))
df_r = df[['id','value']].drop_duplicates().assign(key=1).merge(df_new_row.assign(key=1),on='key',suffixes=('_2',''))

pd.concat([df,df_l,df_r]).drop('key',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id  id_2 name  value  value_2
0   1     2    a   10.5     20.3
1   1     3    a   10.5     30.1
2   2     1    a   20.3     10.5
3   2     3    a   20.3     30.1
4   3     1    a   30.1     10.5
5   3     2    a   30.1     20.3
0   1     4    a   10.5     40.7
1   2     4    a   20.3     40.7
2   3     4    a   30.1     40.7
0   4     1    a   40.7     10.5
1   4     2    a   40.7     20.3
2   4     3    a   40.7     30.1
```

Comment: @SRingne Did this solution help?